# Installing Tomcat and more on a remote virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, remote-desktop, remote-access

My university has setup an account for me on a Virtual Machine running Ubuntu.

I am able to connect to the machine using WinSCP with the SSH address of the server provided to me.

Now I would like to install basic server softwares like Tomcat etc on the system, but I am not sure how to install software on a remote virtual machine.

Comment: Do you have root-access (i.e. an administrator account) in the virtual machine?

Comment: This question is abandoned - if you feel this is in error, please flag for the moderators with a reason why and they'll reopen it. :)

Answer (score -1):

When I first started out I found ubuntuguide to be -very- helpful.
http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Natty

If you don't have root access, this gets alot more complicated and I suggest you ask your network admin to help you.

Make sure you use the ubuntu guide associated with the version if ubuntu installed. Natty is the newest release.